# Retrieve data from MySQL database based on Wordpress Page ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a travel guide website which I am developing with `WordPress` which contains destination guides. On the destination guides pages I have a `sidebar` which displays destination statistics  (currency, time zone etc).

I have to create a new sidebar for each page each time changing these values. Is it possible to create a `MySQL` database with these values and then insert some PHP code that will identify what country page is loaded and insert the corresponding values so that I can use a single sidebar for all pages.

I am fairly proficient with `html/css`  but my understanding of PHP is limited. Any advice as to how this is best achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many different sidebars would you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)? They're any arbitrary pieces of data that you can associate with any post/page. So you could have a key `my_site_currency` (make sure they're easily distinguishable and unique), and each guide page would have a different value for that key.

WordPress provides a basic interface to manage them, but if you want a nicer UI (i.e. a separate metabox for *just* your values on *just* the guide pages in the admin) then you might want to check out the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Comment: Thanks dalbaeb, the Advance Custom Fields plugin is exactly what I was looking for. The only problem I have now is that I have 7 pages for each country, all of which should share the same sidebar.

I don't want to have to fill in these custom fields 7 times, is it possible to have these pages inherit the custom fields from a parent page?

Comment: @lupo I'm afraid ACF doesn't support inheritance, it's something you'd need to do yourself. You could write a script that gets all pages, cycles through them and adds appropriate fields based on page name (or any other differentiating parameter).